# Safari Driver Config in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to launch a Safari browser like chrome driver config from JMeter and calculate render time of a website page.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: why do you want to use Jmeter to calculate render time?

Comment: Becuase I want to do Automation using Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

For the time being there is no support of Safari browser in WebDriver Sampler plugin and [it isn't planned to be added in foreseeable future](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Roadmap/) so if you really need Safari you can either develop your tests in Java + [JUnit](http://junit.org/) and import created tests into JMeter using [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) sampler or directly write Selenium code in the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language.

You will need [Selenium Java Client driver](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) library with dependencies in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try it if I can get a better option.